# Remote tabs in struts2-jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, struts2, struts2-jquery

Am using `struts2 jquery` tabbed pannel to display tabs in my webpage . 
Each tab will contain a grid which will hit the server to get values to the grid . 
I successfully  achieved in loading data on click of the respective tabs.

**Issue :**

I found that , on each click of tab the page  is getting reloaded , But i want the page and its content (Including the Grid ) to be loaded once for the session .

Please advice me what to do further .

i referred the below link : [Struts2-Jquery Showcase](http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action)

In the above link please navigate : `Widgets -> Tabs -> Remote Tabs with Topics`

I tried the exact procedure given in the website but of no use .

If needed any code for clarification . please let me know .

**FYI :** Any negative voting , please guide me what is the reason for .

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the attribute `cache=true` to the [`TabbedPanelTag`](https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/TabbedPanelTag) tag so

```
<sj:tabbedpanel id="remotetabs" selectedTab="1" show="true" cache="true">
        <sj:tab id="tab1" href="%{remoteurl1}" label="Remote Tab One"/>
        <sj:tab id="tab2" href="%{remoteurl2}" label="Remote Tab Two"/>
</sj:tabbedpanel>
```